# Highlight same field twice with different settings

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to return multiple highlights of the same field but with different fragment sizes. One would have a smaller fragment size and be used as a preview for the user before they open the document to see the full result.

Below is what I was thinking the request might look like (definitely not a valid query though). doc_body with large fragment size and doc_body_short with just 100 character fragments as the preview.

```
highlight: {
  fields: {
    doc_body: {
      fragment_size: 200000,
    },
    doc_body_short: {
      fields: { doc_body: {} },
      fragment_size: 100,
    },
  },
}
```

As far as I can tell this doesn't look possible but any advice would be great.